# What is the syntax for running commands inside a docker container in docker-compose.yaml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a image defined as follows:

```
php-enc:
      container_name: php-apache
      image: php:8.0-apache
      volumes:
        - ./php/src:/var/www/html/
      ports:
        - 8000:80
      
      depends_on:
            - db
```

Now i want to run a command inside this container after building this. What I am doing is using the command

```
docker exec -it php-apache bash
```

This takes me into the container and I use another command

```
docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

After this mysqli is installed in the php-apache container.

Now I want include all of this into the docker-compose file, So I tried

```
command: sh -c  "docker-php-ext-install mysqli"
```

```
php-enc:
  container_name: php-apache
  image: php:8.0-apache
  command: sh -c  "docker-php-ext-install mysqli"
  volumes:
    - ./php/src:/var/www/html/
  ports:
    - 8000:80
  
  depends_on:
        - db
```

But it is not working. The container stops running

I want to know how to use command in docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the **command** in your docker-compose.yml file should like this:

```yaml
command: sh -c 'docker-php-ext-install mysqli && apache2-foreground'
```

---

And why your **php-apache** stopds running, cause's:

the command: `sh -c  "docker-php-ext-install mysqli"` does not remain in foreground process after it's execution, which is required for the container to remain running

Answer (score 1):

You should run any installation and setup commands like this in a Dockerfile.  This will give you a custom image that contains your application's dependencies.

The minimal form of this would contain a Dockerfile with just a `FROM` line with your current image name, and then `RUN` any commands you need.

```bash
FROM php:8.0-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-enc:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./php/src:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    depends_on:
      - db
  db: { ... }
```

**Make sure to delete the `image:` line from your Compose file.**  Leaving it in will apparently work, but replace the actual `php:8.0-apache` image with what you've built, which leads to confusing results later.

Also consider using the Dockerfile `COPY` directive to include your application code in the image as well

```bash
COPY ./php/src/ /var/www/html/
```

This will also let you delete the `volumes:` from your Compose file and give you a self-contained runnable image.  You could push that image to a registry and run it elsewhere without needing to have a separate copy of the application code.  This also would mean that edits on your host system won't be visible in a container without rebuilding the image (this is a normal workflow in most compiled languages but may not be what you're used to in PHP).

There are other Dockerfile directives like `EXPOSE` and `CMD` but you don't need them here; the information about how to run the main container process gets inherited from the base image.